# Matplotlib Errorbar behaviour with NaNs

Tags: python, matplotlib, nan

I have some data y plotted against x with asymmetric error bars yerr (`=[up, down]`). The data, y, contains some `np.nan` values at the end and likewise for yerr. However, when I plot the data using matplotlib's `errorbar` function, it gets this weird marker behaviour:

[image: See around 30 on x axis]

What could cause this? I ran a few checks  and the nan values line up, meaning that they shouldn't be plotted at all!

Heres the function:

`axis.errorbar(profile.R, profile.M, yerr=profile.MW, fmt='b.')`

`axis.set_ylim(axis.get_ylim()[::-1])`

and here's some pictures:
after re-phrase: `axis.errorbar(profile.R, profile.M, yerr=(profile.MW[0], profile.MW[1]), fmt='b.')`, it still produces the same plot
after re-phrase: `axis.errorbar(profile.R, profile.M, yerr=(profile.MW[1], profile.MW[1]), fmt='b.')`
[image: Only with up errorbars]

I've also downgraded matplotlib and it still doesn't work!

But when I take the values out of their np.arrays for the last 8 elements by hand (`axis.errorbar([32.9592, 34.60716, 36.33696,  38.15418,  40.06254,  42.06576,  44.16756, 46.37724],[np.nan, 28.18328608, 27.41428602, np.nan, 27.30407038, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], yerr=[[np.nan, 1.16532339, 0.73753135, np.nan, 0.68722997, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, 1.16532339, 0.73753135, np.nan, 0.68722997, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]])`)

[image: WTF it works now?]
it works!! WTF!

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: what does `nan` means in your case? matplotlib skips x/y data containing nans, but apparently doesn't know exactly what to do with nans in error bars.

Comment: np.nan is Not-a-number by numpy's definition.

Comment: I know what `np.nan` is. I asked what it means in "your case". If you know, you can decide what to do with nans in the `yerr`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be. Show us some of your data and code. Version related? I don't think so, I am on `matplotlib 1.3.1`

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> from numpy import *
>>> x=arange(10)*1.
>>> y=random.randint(0,20,size=10)*1.
>>> plt.plot(x, y, 'o-')
>>> y[6]=np.nan
>>> y[8]=np.nan
>>> e=random.random(size=10)
>>> e[6]=np.nan
>>> e[8]=np.nan
>>> e1=random.random(size=10)
>>> e1[8]=np.nan
>>> e1[6]=np.nan
>>> e0=vstack((e,e1))
>>> plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=e)
<Container object of 3 artists>
>>> x
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
>>> y
array([ 12.,   7.,   2.,   4.,  16.,   4.,  nan,   5.,  nan,  14.])
>>> e
array([ 0.55292182,  0.18636933,  0.4564491 ,  0.74029   ,  0.54939223,
        0.98015167,         nan,  0.08164338,         nan,  0.1865567 ])
>>> e1
array([ 0.31619386,  0.06603335,  0.63795806,  0.70372424,  0.8639665 ,
        0.01439499,         nan,  0.73742553,         nan,  0.06838048])
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I was distracted for a time.
Your graph has the same problem as mine!

Comment: Also I've now added more data in the question!